# Pass realtime information between activities

Tags: android, google-maps

I have two activities in my Android project:

1. Google Map Activity
2. List Activity

I'm trying to pass an item's location information to GMAP Activity and add it as an overlay to  the map. I know i have to use putExtra and getExtra but I want to add that location to the Google Map and show it to user when user taps on a List Activity item. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ListView's setOnItemClickListener, and start an new GMAP in your implementation of this method.
Following is sample code:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id){
        // Start your Activity according to the item just clicked.
        //also put extras.
        Intent newIntent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, GMAPActivity.class);
        newIntent.putExtra(key,value);
        startActivity(newIntent);
    }
};
```